# Get-ChildItem with Logging and Copy-Item in one command

Tags: powershell, logging, copy, pipeline

Basically my goal is copy content of a folder to another folder with exclusion one name and also log everything what has been copied.

I'm stock on logging Get-ChildItem command combined with Pipeline --> Copy-Item

Bellow command will put to log file all data from command Get-ChildItem:

```
$SourcePath = "D:\TEST"
$DestPath = "C:\TEST"
$LogDetailFile = "C:\Temp\CopyDetail.log"
$Exclude = "!_Archive_!"

Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse | Where {$_.FullName -notmatch $Exclude} |
Select FullName | Add-Content $LogDetailFile
```

When I extra add with next Pipeline command to copy them to $DestPath it wont work:

```
Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse | Where {$_.FullName -notmatch $Exclude} |
Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $DestPath $_.FullName.Substring($SourcePath.length)} | 
Add-Content $LogFile
```

When I done it without logging options, then everything works fine and whole data is copied:

```
Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse | Where {$_.FullName -notmatch $Exclude} |
Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $DestPath $_.FullName.Substring($SourcePath.length)}
```

I tried already switch pipelines between but it don't work.
What I'm missing here? How to copy everything from one Folder to another and log all copied items to logfile?

Right now If I want to have 2 things - logging and copy those items I need to run 2 commands, just want to have it in one command.

Comment: Left this outside the answer but I believe you should use `Select-Object -Expand FullName` otherwise without expand you will get string representation of objects like `@{FullName=.....}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForEach-Object` can help you here, the reason why combining both breaks is because neither of those cmdlets (`Add-Content` and `Copy-Item`) produce output so there is nothing to pipe to.

```
$SourcePath = 'D:\TEST'
$DestPath = 'C:\TEST'
$LogDetailFile = 'C:\Temp\CopyDetail.log'
$Exclude = '!_Archive_!'

Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.FullName -notmatch $Exclude) {
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination { Join-Path $DestPath $_.FullName.Substring($SourcePath.Length) }
        $_ | Select-Object FullName # Probably need `-ExpandProperty` here
    }
} | Add-Content $LogDetailFile
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :) Its save my brain from blow up ;)
Now its copy and log it. Cool!